# How to check if this function has a partial derivative

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

How do I check if the partial derivative (according to vector ex) exists in a piecewise function? Consider this function $f$:

\begin{cases} 
      \frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\ 
      0 & (x,y) = (0,0)\\ 
   \end{cases}

I calculated the derivative by definition for the first expression and I obtained 0. In order to check if the derivative exists do I have to calculate the same limit but considering the second exprssion? In this case f(0,0) is not relevant to check whether the derivative exists, right? The limit by definition of derivative (I don't know what to call it) has to be the same when I consider either expression but t -> 0 in either limit, right?

Comment: This function isn't even continuous at $(0,0)$ let alone differentiable.

Comment: I don't know what you computed, but it sounds like you were computing the wrong thing. To compute the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ you *must* use the limit definition, which uses $f(0,0)$, of course. Note that $f(h,0)-f(0,0) = \frac 1h$, so we even have problems before we divide by $h$ and try to take the limit. Indeed, the function is not continuous at $0$ along either axis.